# Interpreting GEE unmixing SMA classification output results

Tags: google-earth-engine, classification

I would like help interpreting unmixing SMA (Spectral Mixture Analysis) output results in GEE.

I have identified endmembers by class as the following:
4 classes: 0 = forest; 1 = savanna; 2 = shadeWater; 3 = bareground

The following is the code snippet where I merged all the training points together.

```
//////////////////////////

// merge all the points in the same feature collection 
    var points = forest.merge(savanna).merge(shadeWater).merge(bareground)
    print(points)

// extract the bands values using the points defined above
    var endmembers1 = greenestComposite.first().sampleRegions({
  // Get the sample from the polygons FeatureCollection.
  collection: points,
  // Keep this list of properties from the polygons.
  properties: ['class'],
  // Set the scale to get Landsat pixels in the polygons.
  scale: 30
});
print(endmembers1.toList(4), 'endmembers1')
```

The following is the return of the pixel information:

```
var unmix = image
  .clip(DAD1geom)
  .select(bands)
  .unmix(endmembers2.getInfo(), true, true);//the trues constrain the proportion results between 0 and 1

  return unmix.addBands(image)
};
////////////////////////////
```

Here are my results for one pixel after the mapUnmix() algorithm:

```
FINAL: Image (13 bands)
band_0: 0.19283048751277443
band_1: 0
band_2: 0.2873728238557205
band_3: 0.5197966886315166
B1: 279
B2: 502
B3: 529
B4: 2122
B5: 2028
B6: 1085
B7: 2969
NDVI: 0.6009052991867065
DOY: 16
```

[image: forest endmember image]

I am interested in the band_ values because it tells me the proportional values of each class, band for that particular pixel.

What I don't understand is whether each band represents each endmember?

Does band 0 represent forest, band 1 represent savanna, band 2 represent shadewater and band 3 represent bareground for each pixel?

Or do the bands differ based on which endmember I have assigned and am looking at?

I am confused because those bands don't tell me what I expected. Therefore I can't truly tell what the band values mean.

What does the output of bands return?

Comment: Please edit your question and add relevant part of your code to the body of the question. Linked resources tend to get lost in time.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites. We're a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.